# Pass point object into @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring-boot, request, geometry

I'm developing rest api service using spring boot.My project has an entity class named CarWash with fields

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
@Column(columnDefinition = "Point", name = "lon_lat")
    private Point lonLat;
 @Column(name = "address")
private String address;
```

This is my controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "owner/carWashs", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")


 @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> createCarWash(@RequestParam(value = "sid", required = true, defaultValue = "") String sid,
                                               @RequestBody CarWash carWash) throws TimeoutException, SocketTimeoutException, SocketException {
        final Integer id = checkSession(sid);
        System.out.println(carWash.getLonLat());
        System.out.println(carWash.getAddress());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(createCarWashLogic(carWash));
    }
```

When i call this method using this json `{"address":"qwerty"}`it's work fine.
The question is how can i add lonLat property into request body in order to jackson will be able to parse it to POINT object?

Comment: use embedded json object with all fields Point object contains

Comment: Create an instance of the CarWash class and serialize it using Jackson. You could always use custom marshallers for classes that you don't control if you don't like the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a

`class Point{
 String attribute1;
String attribute2;
}`

send Carwash json like

`{
"address":"qwerty",
"lonLat" : {
"attribute1":"value",
"attribute2":"value"
}
}`

and jackson will set the attribute values accordingly.

Comment: My lonLat as an object of import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point class, if write {"lonLat":{
 "x" : 32,
     "y" : 43

}} it give my jsonParse exception

Comment: According to me, for default jackson parsing it must have a default constructor and public setters for the attributes of the class or the attribute must be public. And as I can see the Point class it just has a constructor open to set the coordinates and that too in form of coordinate object. So you may have to get that coordinates from json, map it into a custom user defined class and then manually set it into Point class using its constructor.

Comment: I add lon,lat  fields to my class and user native sql script to create POINT lonLat object

Answer (score 0):

Your **Point** [class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.11/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Point.java) has a field **CoordinateSequence coordinates**, and that field has fields **int X, int Y, int Z, int M**. So your json string should be like this:

```
{
  "address": "some address",
  "lonLat": {
    "coordinates": {
      "X": 123,
      "Y": 123,
      "Z": 123,
      "M": 123,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but i tried in this way, JsonFormat exception

Comment: @Алмас Абдразак Is the class in the link in my answer the class you use? And did you copy json string from my answer? If you copy from answer I had forgotten to close parentheses(I corrected it now), can you try again? And if it is not the class you use can you share a link to **Point** class